# Get the post_id of a new post

Tags: posts, actions, save-post, id

There are several ways to get the id of a post after it has been saved (auto, etc.), but is there a way to get the post id immediately after you create a new post?

I am trying to create a directory using the post id, but I cannot seem to get a static post id.

the code below seems to work but I get an auto incremented id back every time the new post auto saves the draft, I continually get a new number.

```
function myfunction( $id ) {
        if (!file_exists("/www/foo/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id)) {
            mkdir("/www/foo/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id, 0777);
        }
}
add_action('save_post', 'myfunction');
```

I would like to get the post id that it will be saved as. Surely WP has a method for determining this correct? Or does the draft auto save every minute incrementing the id by one until the actual 'publish' button is clicked?

thoughts?

cheers!
bo

Comment: We already had that Q, but I can't find it. To answer your Q in short: No. How should there an ID, then the ID is the _unique identifier number_ inside the DB? ;)

Comment: Kaiser what do you mean? I cant figure out your second sentence.

Comment: Robert, if the answer posted doesnt solve your problem can you explain why you would expect something other than an auto incremented response? Did you mean the same post when saved again returns a new ID?

Comment: @miahelf correct, if I monitor the uploads folder, everytime it auto saves, the id increments by 1

Comment: @kaiser I get the uid thing, but when for instance a new post is created, does WP start at the last id (auto-increment)? for example lets start at 1. so after clicking new post, does WP assign the post `1`? then everytime it auto saves it increments. heres the stinger... upon clicking save, does WP then atually save the post as id `1`? or the next available incremented id?

Comment: Yes, you got an ID after saving. And yes, it increments, but it doesn't fill gaps that may occur from deleting posts. And a revision is a post-type of its own with a unique ID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this...

```
add_action('post_updated', 'myfunction');

function myfunction( $post_id ) {

    global $post;

        if (!file_exists("/www/foo/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $post_id)) {
            mkdir("/www/foo/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $post_id, 0777);
        }
}
```

**NOTE:** Change from `save_posts` to `post_updated` which will stop the duplicate issue as it fires on **"publish"** only and not every time you hit `add new` or `update` etc.

**NOTE:** I verified this for you by testing the snippet above - all good.

**NOTE:** You can also use `(wp_upload_dir() . $post_id, 0777)` if you want a path that is more transportable or if you are developing a plugin or theme for public use.

Comment: @roberthuttinger I'm confused, how does this not solve the issue? You want to get the post_id of a new post and create a directory such as - /path/bla/uploads/post-id/  - the above code does exactly that.

Comment: Easy? Are you implying that I somehow might be turning over tables and breaking my keyboard because you won't mark this answer? :) - I'm not that invested believe me so don't read into my message as anything other than a question and a re-statement of an answer which is directly related to your question because your first comment to me is `confusing` as you say `it will work` yet `doesn't solve the issue` yet it directly addresses the issue. My follow up to that is an attempt to gain some clarification that we're on the same page so I can continue to help you until you have solved this problem

Comment: I hope that clears things up for you... Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Had a chance to test it, perfect! The `post_updated` must have been the correct thing to tap into. Now to do some homework onthe differences between `save_post`, `post_save`, and `post_updated` thanks!

Comment: `save_post` and `wp_insert_post` we're creating folder-ID entries every-time I touched either Add New post or Update or Publish. So simply adding a post then publishing it would create two folders with incremented IDs (one correct and one-incorrect) and similarly if you updated the post you'd get another folder with another ID. `post_updated` being the only action that committed the official ID once and once only. I'll be looking further into understanding the mechanism behind how WP handles IDs in relation to the former actions too because I don't really get it after this experiment. Enjoy!